# Efficiency: NSUserDefaults vs loading/saving an NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults

I have a bunch of game data (10 integers) I need to save and load.

Is it more efficient to use a NSMutableDictionary, add the items and save it, or to save each item into NSUserDefaults?(NSMutableDictionary is already created, when the data is loaded in on startup)

The same question goes for the loading, is it faster to load the dictionary and then extract the data, or just get each one from NSUserDefaults one at a time?

A benefit of NSUserDefaults is obviously the global access.

Comment: How big is a bunch? I doubt you'd notice much difference between the two.

Comment: I'd say that's premature optimization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a trifling amount of data and relative efficiency doesn't even come into it. Go for the simplest code in this case, which is user defaults.